# FFmpeg export frames listed in file (including duplicates)

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

**Problem**

I have a list of frames that I want to extract from some video file.
The list might look like this:

```
1,6,6,10,15,20,20,25,25,50
```

In reality there are thousands of frames.

How do I extract these frames into images or video in efficient way?

**What I have tried**

1. Using FFmpeg select filter. I could create huge string from file like `select=eq(\n,1)+eq(\n,6)+...` but the problem is that I cannot export duplicates this way. Also I am not sure about the performance.
2. Exporting all frames to folder, then copying relevant frames to another folder. This is the current solution, which is painfully slow and takes a lot of storage.
3. Using python and opencv. I could use `cv.VideoCapture` functionality to read frame by frame and save the ones I need. The problem is that before the extraction, I need to change framerate of the video to some constant framerate (very important). That's why ffmpeg is preferred, because I could add fps filter to filterchain. I know that it's possible to read frames with opencv by using ffmpeg backend, but I couldn't find how to change the framerate beforehand. Reencoding the video before is not preferred as it wastes time and possibly decreases video quality.
4. Write a new ffmpeg filter. While I am not in close relationship with C or ffmpeg API, I tried editing fps filter to drop frames that are not in the list. This kind of worked but I couldn't solve the problem with duplicating frames. I wonder if that's possible to do and if I should continue trying with this approach. Having ffmpeg filter would be probably the best option.

Comment: What is the maximum number of duplicates for a frame?

Comment: @Gyan Maximum is not know and each frame can have different amount of duplicates. Could as well be a list of only one repeating frame.

Comment: It will be faster to extract each selected frame once and then make copies of those files.

Answer (score 0):

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LST=(1 6 6 10)
TOT=${#LST[*]}
for (( i=0; i<=$(( $TOT -1 )); i++ )); do
  ffmpeg -i "input 1.mkv" -filter:v "select='eq(n,${LST[$i]})'" -vsync vfr "/tmp/img_${i}_${LST[$i]}.jpg"
done
```

it is not fast, but works ☺

Comment: Yeah, it's not fast, at all...
For every iteration ffmpeg traverses video file until gets to the needed frame.
Imagine getting last video frame multiple times. Every time it has to go through whole video to do so.

Even extracting all frames and copying is faster.